# Reactstrap with CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, reactstrap

I need to interconnect CSS modules and Reactstrap.

I found different solutions, but they were all far from ideal.

Maybe someone knows an elegant solution and can offer? The problem lies in the fact that Reactstrap provides ready-made components and the problem arises how to make CSS modules out of them?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You see: we dont know which solutions you studied, and why you don't like them. If you want people to give you *different* solutions, you *have* to include the things you tried so far. Otherwise you might end up getting the same advice again.